# Programs working under WINE

Tags: windows, wine

I am having an issue of opening an **.exe** file with WINE. For some Windows programs WINE works, for others it does not. I want to know the dependencies for WINE. How can i check whether a particular .exe file will work perfectly with WINE.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wine provides information on *application compatibility with Wine* in it's official website under: [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/)

[image: wineDBApps]

Answer (score 0):

If the *.exe* is in a partition that does not have the execute permission (more likely in dual boot systems with the Windows' partitions like *ntfs, fat*), the *executable .exe* file will fail to run. To solve this copy the executable file to your home folder (or any with the *ext** partitions or with *RW* permissions), probably change the file's property to allow execution and then try executing. Or change the partition's property to allow execution of executables.

See if this helps...

If `sda1` is already mounted to `/media/your_partition_label`, you could unmount it with:

```
sudo umount /media/windows
```

Next create the directory `windows` in `/media/`:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
```

Edit the `/etc/fstab` as below: <sup>(*for NTFS partition*)</sup>

```
/dev/sda1  /media/your_partition_label ntfs-3g  rw,nodev,noexec,auto,nouser,async,locale=en_US.utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0002 0 0
```

(**Note**: change ***uid*** and ***gid*** values as for the user. To get the uid and gid of a user you can use the command `id -u username` and `id -g username` resp.)

Now you can mount these with the command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Then you should be able to run executable files (*having the execute permission*) in that *partition/mount*.